# Jmeter Size of CSV file(Use CSV Data Set Config)

Tags: csv, jmeter

I want to know the best pratice of Jmeter csv file. Maybe I have a huge csv file, but I don't know in what scope it is reasonable
e.g. Will 4G csv files affect jmeter test

I want to know the best pratice of Jmeter csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSV Data Set Config is "the best practice", if you take a look at other JMeter components which are capable of getting data from files:

- [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function documentation states:

  > The function is not suitable for use with large files, as the entire file is stored in memory. For larger files, use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element or [StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile).

Alternative option would be ingesting your CSV file into a [relational database](https://www.w3schools.in/sql/database) and use JMeter's [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) to read the data from the database. See [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter) article for more details.